# Issue with ggplot legend + label placement when using conditional table filter

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, label

I created a (messy) shinyApp where if the inputs of char1 and char2 are not found in the dataframe it rearranges the columns of the dataframe so that the order matches and the dataframe can be successfully filtered.

See below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

#create sample dataframe
player1 <- c("Mario","Mario", "Peach")
player2 <- c("Luigi", "Peach", "Luigi")
pcnt_wins <- c(.75,.20,.55)
pcnt_loss <- c(.25,.80,.45)
data <- data.frame(player1, player2, pcnt_wins, pcnt_loss)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("char1", "Character 1:",
              c("Mario" = "Mario",
                "Luigi" = "Luigi",
                "Peach" = "Peach")),
  selectInput("char2","Character 2",
              c("Mario" = "Mario",
                "Luigi" = "Luigi",
                "Peach" = "Peach")),
  tableOutput("data_table"),
  textOutput("text"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #intermediate steps to create output table 
  table_filtered <- reactive({
    data %>% filter((player1 == input$char1 & player2 == input$char2) |
                    (player1 == input$char2 & player2 == input$char1))
      })
  
  
  pie_filtered <- reactive ({
    if (!(input$char1 %in% table_filtered()$player1 ))  {
      table_filtered() %>%
        dplyr::mutate(player1_new = player2, 
                      player2_new = player1) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(pcnt_wins_new = 1 - pcnt_wins,
                      pcnt_loss_new = 1 - pcnt_loss) %>%
        dplyr::select(player1 = player1_new,
                      player2 = player2_new,
                      pcnt_wins = pcnt_wins_new,
                      pcnt_loss = pcnt_loss_new) %>%
        dplyr::filter(player1 == input$char1 & player2 == input$char2)
      
    } else {
      table_filtered() %>%
        dplyr::filter(player1 == input$char1 & player2 == input$char2)
    }
  })
  
  
  
  character <- reactive({ # first column
    c(pie_filtered()$player1, 
      pie_filtered()$player2) })
  
  pie_win_pcnt <- reactive({ #second column
    c(as.double(pie_filtered()$pcnt_wins),
      as.double(pie_filtered()$pcnt_loss)) })
  
  pie_final <- reactive({
    data.frame(character = character(), pie_win_pcnt = pie_win_pcnt())
  })
  
  #create table output 
  output$data_table <- renderTable({
    pie_filtered()
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({ class(pie_final()$pie_win_pcnt) })
  
  #create plot output 
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    pie_final() %>%
      mutate(csum = rev(cumsum(rev(100*pie_win_pcnt))), 
             pos = 100*pie_win_pcnt/2 + lead(csum, 1),
             pos = if_else(is.na(pos), 100*pie_win_pcnt/2, pos)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = "", y = 100*pie_win_pcnt, fill = character)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
      coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
      geom_col(width = 1, color =1) + 
      theme_void() +
      geom_label_repel(
        aes(y = pos, 
            label = paste0(round(100*pie_win_pcnt,0), "%")),
            size = 6, 
            nudge_x = 1, 
            show.legend = FALSE)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

The table looks like this

| player1 | player2 | pcnt_wins | pcnt_loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mario | Luigi | .75 | .25 |
| Mario | Peach | .20 | .80 |
| Peach | Luigi | .55 | .45 |

When the input char1 is not in order as shown in the table (i.e. char1 is Luigi and char2 is Peach)

[image: I get a perfect pie chart]

When input char1 is found in the order as shown in the table (i.e. char1 is Peach and char2 is Luigi) The percentage labels are placed in the wrong positions.

[image: I get this not so perfect pie chart]

I'm not sure why this is happening. I suspect it has to do with my wonky if else statement but I haven't been able to figure out how to fix this issue.

I would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you do not account for the order of the `character` column when computing the positions for the labels, i.e. your computation is only correct when the data is already in the right order.

To fix your issue `arrange` your data by `character` first, then compute the cumulative sum and finally compute the position.

```
# create plot output
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  pie_final() %>%
    arrange(desc(character)) %>%
    mutate(
      csum = 100 * cumsum(pie_win_pcnt),
      pos = .5 * (csum + lag(csum, default = 0))
    ) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = "", y = 100 * pie_win_pcnt, fill = character)) +
    coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
    geom_col(width = 1, color = 1) +
    theme_void() +
    geom_label_repel(
      aes(
        y = pos,
        label = paste0(round(100 * pie_win_pcnt, 0), "%")
      ),
      size = 6,
      nudge_x = 1,
      show.legend = FALSE
    )
})
```

[image]